# Simplification of ODE using Power Series methods to find a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I have to substitute the power series $$y(x,r)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(r)x^{n+r}$$ into the ODE $L[y]=x^2y''+xp(x)y'+q(x)y=0$ which I need to simplify to $L[y(x,r)]=x^r(r-r_1)^2$ I've got as far as:$$L[y(x,r)]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(c_n(r)(n+r)(n+r-1)+\sum_{k=0}^{n}(p_{n-k}(k+r)+q_{n-k})c_k(r))x^{n+r}$$Can anyone please help with this simplification? Thanks.

Original question 19a attached. My workings to follow. Thanks in advance for your help.[image: question]

Here is the start of my answer

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzHug.jpg]

Here is the rest of my workings. I'm stuck at this point so any help/advice would be great, thanks!

[image]

Comment: What are c, p and q?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that. I'll edit my original question.

Comment: I don't think your round brackets match up. FYI commenters don't get notified of OP edits :P

Comment: @BCLC I've checked and the brackets are correct. It's the sum of a sum if that makes sense. Thanks for the FYI.

Comment: What are $p_i$'s ? $q_i$'s? What is $r_1$?

Comment: Like this [?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IXrnu.png)

Comment: Yes except x0=0 and R(x) is not r/r1. r1 is the single repeat root of the indicial equation fi(r)=(r-r1)^2=0. @BCLC

Comment: Well why don't you include it in the question then? This question seems to lack of a lot of details.

Comment: @BCLC Sorry, it's a lengthy question and I was trying to cut it down to just the bit I was stuck on. I'll try to post the full question as I don't want to make it any harder for you than it already is!

Comment: please do not split your answer in multiple answers. You can always edit your answer if you want to add something

Comment: Samil, what others said. Don't split the post into many parts. While your handwriting is much more legible than some other posters TeX it does have the disadvantage that not even google can search it. Do consider learning TeX. Comes in handy.